# Is it possible to turn visible the invisible window's borders of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, window, desktop-customization, dwm, visual-styles

### SCENARIO

---

This is a brief introduction for those who don't know the next information:

The new **Windows 10**'s flat window style uses a different window-border mechanism than previous **Windows** versions, which affects in a horrible way the window aspect, and its usage, in the meanning of window-resizing and window-positioning.

**Windows 10** by default has a 1 px. visible border, notice the word "visible", because the reality is that the border width is greater, simply is just an invisible border, that is, the border image resource that **Windows 10** uses it only fills 1 px. of the real width of the window border bounds, no matter how big is the border width, you always will only see 1 px. border, and here you can imagine by yourself the problem that can cause.

In **Windows 10**, as in previous Windows versions, you can perform some registry changes to increase the window borders width, this is an example of what I mean, for **Windows 8**:

[image]

[image]

However, as for the (*bad-design*) "rules" of **Windows 10**, if the user tries to reproduce the same registry trick in this O.S, nothing will change in the window aspect, you'll end up with a geater border, yes, but remember that only 1 px. of that border will be visible, so you'll end up having a damn 1 px. visible border with a big and annonying invisible resize handle.

This poor, bad, unfriendlly, and horrible design decission of **Microsoft** is a fact, as is also a fact that exists much users who loves this 1 px. border aspect, their oppinion is respetable, however, honestlly those users only fix their oppinion on the O.S. aspect, they don't notice the wrong behavior that 1 px. border can cause to they, whch will break the end-user productivity and comfortableness, even just with simple things like trying to move a Window, or trying to difference which window is over to other, because the border of all windows are invisible.

This issue has been discussed over "all" the Internet forums related to **Windows 10** personalization, here is a simple but never-ending discussion topic on a **Microsoft Community** thread for your interest:

- ***[Windows 10 windows' borders are too thin!! - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-windows-borders-are-too-thin/5acd8dff-fc0b-46e5-9598-d52833d54487?auth=1)***

( As you can see, the topic has been created 2 years ago, has +14.000 views, +100 replies, +270 recommends, but ZERO answers and ZERO fixes or responsabilities from **Microsoft** team, yes, is very disgusting. )

### PROBLEM

---

The pressence of that damn and uncustomizable? 1 px. border, there is where all the problems and worst nightmares begins with **Windows 10**.

I always loved to use a program named **[Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/)** in previous Windows versions, which is an application that lets you positionate any window to customizable preestablished positions for any visible window in just one click, however this kind of time-saver window organization applications can't work as expected in **Windows 10** because the damn invisible border, because the size of the invisible borders will be sum when calculating the position for the window, and this is translated into an annonying empty space on the desktop between the positioned windows and the desktop margins...

For those who are familiar with **Sizer**, this is an image to let you understand what I mean, the blank space between positions (which are the size of the damn invisible border of **Windows 10**):
[image]

So, for me and my reasons, having a 1 visible px. border is a very big problem that I'm facing every day using **Windows 10**, I'm really ...desperately jaded.

I won't rollback to a previous **Windows** version because I gain more by using **Windows 10** O.S and its performance advantages, however the 1 px. border is the most horrible disadvantage of this O.S, I would like to feel happy by having a real window border like in previous **Windows** versions, this means a border image that fills the entire border width (like the images of the comparison I published above in the question introduction), I don't want to have a 8 px. border in which only 1 px. is visible, that is crazy, I don't know in what the hell were thinking the devs. who designed **Windows 10**, if you will give the name "Windows" to your own O.S, then try to design and implement a real "window" appearance and beahavior, then avoid implementing invisible window resize handles for the mother of God!!.

### QUESTION

---

At this point, knowing that In **Windows 10** the real border width is 8 px, but only 1 px. is shown, and the rest of the border is just... invisible,

I would like to ask for a possible solution to turn visible the border in **Windows 10**, I mean to have a real window border like in previous **Windows** versions, with a border image resource that fills the entire border width, NOT an invisible border.

I'm aware this question probablly needs advanced knowledges, further investigation and personal testing, because **Google**'s result pages will not show anyone how to solve this issue, all the people talk and discuss about this 1 px. border issue, but no body seems to know a solution, and worst than that, **Microsoft** seems is not listenning to anyone and to the reasonable design of a "window".

I must say that I have an application named **[Windows Style Builder](https://www.vistastylebuilder.com/)** (for **Windows 10** version), which is able to open a **.msstyle** theme file to edit any image resource contained in the theme, that program was the only hope I found to try find and make greater the border image resource to fill the entire real border width, however I tried to make bigger all the border image resources used in **Aero** theme, but **Windows 10** remains showing a 1 px. border, seems no matter how much big is the border image resource used to show the border by the theme, seems the displayed border width is not controlled by the theme itself (I don't really know), so my nightmare is to think that seems a person with reversal engineering knowledges to create a kind of home-made patch to apply to who knows which executable or windows resource could be required to solve this annonying issue of **Windows 10**, I really hope this thing could be solved in a more friendlly way.

I don't know what more to investigate and to try by myself.

### REQUISITES

---

The only requisite I claim for, is that a possible solution **should not** imply using a 3rd party theme like for example **Aerolite**, this is because I'm already using a 3rd party darker windows theme, so If I change to other (light) theme then I will end-up having a new problem.

For that reason, please take really into account that my question is "*How to turn visible the invisible window's borders of Windows 10*", is not "*which 3rd party theme I can install to see window borders in Windows 10?*".

Please also try don't focus the question to **Sizer** alternatives, those alternatives are welcome and appreciated from my side, of course, really, however the real problem is the invisible borders of **Windows 10**, which not only will affect **Sizer**, is a problem that will affect to overall usage of the O.S.

---

### UPDATE

These paragraphs below are just to argument why **[Stardock's WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)** can't be described as a solution in any manner. You can ignore all these words below.

Obviouslly **Stardock's WindowBlinds** will be a good personalization program for other kind of purposses, or for those who feel good using it, but not just for making visible the window borders in **Windows 10**, for these reasons:

( Please note that my intention is not to defame Stardock's products or dev. team, I had bought **[Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)** years ago and Its a very professional application that I think everyone must have for desktop icons organization, I really can't live without **Fences**, so I appreciate Stardock's work. )

- The program uses a kind of special technology that seems is not featured in common Windows themes, because it doesn't apply a theme file neither it doesn't involve a *.msstyles* file that contains the theme resources and settings as we know.
- My affirmation above is argumented because after a file and registry monitoring I didn't discovered how they "add" borders to the windows, the program didn't made anything relevant with Windows themes related registry keys or windows theme files/directories, so I suspect this program must use API hooking techniques on some *UX Theme* Win32 APIs to change the resources at execution time, then an advanced monitoring of the calls to WinAPI functions is required to confirm my suspection.
- It is an application that implies applying a custom **WindowBlinds** theme to "add" borders to the windows, and that consumes much resources, much.
- The program changes the taskbar style and the winstart menu, which affect its behavior, seems the end-user cannot decide to disable those features (I'm not sure), so the usage of **WindowBlinds** limits you to be unable to use programs like **StartIsBack++** to get a decent winstart menu (I tested it, and it breaks **StartIsBack++**), on the other hand, probablly **[Stardock's Windowblinds]** should support their **[Stardock's Start10](http://www.stardock.com/products/start10/)** product, just to mention it for those who feel interested, but in my oppinion it has nothing better than **StartIsBack++**.
- **WindowBlinds** really **does not turn visible the window borders**, what it seems to do is reduce the original window rectangle to print fake borders, which produces a higher non-client rectangle or "invisible window borders rectangle" more annonying than the *Windows 10* default, which totally impossibilites (even more) the usage of programs like **Sizer** and etc. to manage the window positions, because this is the real, modified window rectangle after a **WindowBlinds** theme is applied:

[image]

- We can continue saying that it adds a (unwanted) shadow over the window, even when you disabled all the effect options in the Control Panel settings, this is because as I mentioned at the beginning this program seems is not using common Windows themes, so the control panel options that affects to Window themes will not affect to **WindowBlinds** themes, instead I suspect this program uses API hooking techniques to "create" the theme environment (and fake borders). **WindowsBlinds** has its owns effect configurations.
- As a last disadvantage, **WindowBlinds** is a paid product, and it is a "complete" personalization application, I mean that one person should not think to pay for and to install a full suite of personalization just to try to do a single change in a Windows theme.

Comment: Sizer doesn't fully support Windows 10. However, you can still use Sizer by hovering on one of the window corners and whenever the pointer change to Two-directions arrows, just right-click, and the Sizer menu will popup, enabling you to resize the window from the saved presets. One other thing, if you see any hangs on the windows, just change the Compatibility to Windows 7 and run Sizer as an administration, thus could solve your problem temporarily until the next release of Sizer.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but Sizer fully supports Windows 10, anyways Sizer is a discontinued project, seems there will not be a future version, I'm aware how to use Sizer, I'm using it since the Windows 7 Era, the problem is what I mentioned about the annonying invisible Windows 10's window borders that brokes an intent of personal window organization and the logic of any kind of application used to manage the window positions automation, like Sizer.

Comment: ask this in the Windows Style Builder community. They create a lot of themes, so they can help you. I and 99.99% of the users here never did this and creating bounties over and over again won't help here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, yes of course it is a very reasonable suggestion but just I can't do that because to be honest time ago I have denied my forum access for own personal reasons, if someone has bought WSB like me and could publish this question in WSB forums then I will be very gratefully, thanks again.

Comment: Winaero tweaker can increase it for the aerolite theme. try this.

Comment: You could use Aerolite Theme as [explained here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7935-aerolite-theme-install-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @magicandre1981, harrymc, thanks for comment but as I explained in the question I'm using a custom darker theme for my eyes, is not possible to change to aerolite theme. However could be good to know that a custom theme for Windows 10 like Aerolite has visible borders, that is a proof that the window borders can be turn visible for any other 3rd party theme for Windows 10, the question is: how to?

Comment: Holy f'ing shiznit that's a lot of detail!! Wonder what genius programmer is going to come up with a workable solution to this problem. If there's anyone that could do this, I bet it'd be one of these guys here on SuperUser and/or other SE communities... I look forward to upvoting such a workable solution to this issue since so many people are affected by it, and MS cannot seem to give a solution from what you say. I'll await the working answer and praise the hero who finds this solution.

Comment: "I gain more by using Windows 10 O.S and its performance advantages" Wait, Windows 10 has those? ;P

Comment: Was the anniversary update helpful in this? Window borders have a bit changed there.

Comment: IMHO the best solution would have been to publicly stone the one who had the idea of one-pixel window borders, and publicly stone the ones who implemented it. ;-) Only a monopolist can enforce such stupidity!

Comment: @U.Windl: You speak for the masses.  It is now 2021, and MFST has not seen it fit to fix this problem. Overlapping windows is a cognitive nightmare. This is what happens when aesthetics trumps function.

Comment: @user36800 I don't see whether "aesthetics trumps" at all: Requiring that apps implement their own window borders surely doesn't help aesthetics. I'd also like to note that the problem is most visible when you have overlapping PuTTY windows on your desktop, especially when they have a common baseline (talking of vertical text alignment).

Comment: @U. Windl: I'm saying that letting users choose their own visible borders is good for functional reasons, e.g., you work more efficiently if you don't disrupt your mental flow and waste cognitive energy trying to figure out which window is on top, and where one window ends and the other begins. People who like the thin borders are enamoured of the slick, clean "look". So the benefit of thin windows is aesthetic, and it exacts a debilitating functional cost in terms of doing work. Many people have expressed this (hence my reference to "the masses"). We're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a conjecture: All custom themes are based on editing built-in `aero.msstyles` or `aerolite.msstyles`, located at `%windir%\Resources\Themes\aero`. `aero` comes with fixed 1px border, while [aerolite](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7935-aerolite-theme-install-windows-10-a.html) has 1-8px border, configurable through [registry](http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-to-decrease-window-border-size-and-padding-in-windows-8/) or [WSB](http://virtualcustoms.net/showthread.php/35027-How-do-you-adjust-window-border-width) (9px or above remains invisible). So far there is no public documentation on how to build msstyles from scratch. As such whether your theme has configurable visible border depends on which default msstyles was based on.

You are advised to seek professional assistance at [Virtual Customs](http://virtualcustoms.net/showthread.php/35027-How-do-you-adjust-window-border-width).

Comment: I give up. I've experimented on multiple msstyles files with WSB to no avail. End up screen flashing several times already. This is not something a novice can solve.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer adding more details. I will try asking on Virtual Customs, however I think they don't know how to do this, because **Mr Grim**'s themes for Windows 10 are borderless (better said: a "fixed" 1 px border), the theme that I'm actually using is a dark theme made by him.

Comment: A quick look at **Mr Grim**'s [themes](http://virtualcustoms.net/forumdisplay.php/1197-Mr-GRiM-s-Windows-10-Themes), there are a few with borders similar to aerolite, like Poison, Equinox and H2O.

Comment: Woah! my fault, at first sight seems true what you are saying!!! I will analyze those themes during today and if I'm able to find the "key" in WSB I'll accept your answer, thanks a lot for the orientation.

Comment: I tested the borders and is much better than using **WindosBlinds** with their fake borders, the **Mr. Grim** themes borders are "real", so I have no problems when moving/positioning a window because the borders are "normal", and **Sizer** app works fine again with the themes you've mentioned. I think it should be as you said, a theme based on the **aerolite.msstyles** is the key, so now for me is just a matter of editting that file with WBS, to export/import values from the **Mr. Grim**'s theme based on **aero.msstyles** to a new theme from scractch based on **aerolite.msstyles**,thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it might assist you.  If you go to System or right click "this computer" and go to properties, then on the left click "advanced system settings", click the button "settings" in the "performance" group box under the "advanced" tab, and then set the machine to "Adjust for best performance".  After you do that click OK and let the settings kick in.  Then try dragging a window around and you will see the "invisible" border box you are looking for that exists in prior versions of windows.  Perhaps you can leverage that?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just need to disable the "Show window content while moving the window" (I'm not sure is that is the name in English) there is no need to disable all the graphic features, however as you know that will not make visible the borders, it will draw a rectangle over the window while moving, which in any case could be the same what I'm looking for, but really thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

[Stardock's WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) ($9.99, 30-day trial available) claims to be able to do this.

Here is an example from their demo for Windows 10 :

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, do you know whether to do that it implies applying a custom Stardock theme?, that would be a very inconvenient for me as I explained in the question I'm using a darker 3rd party theme, however, you gave good info, I'm actually installing a Windows 10 Virtual Machine to proceed to test the WindowBlinds demo with basic reversal enineering registry and file  techniques to see if I can discover "the secret" about how they did that.

Comment: Unfortunately using **WindowBlinds** is the worst possible solution, it can't be described as solution, I detail the arguments in the update that I did to my question. Thanks again for answer!.

Comment: All of Stardock's products are based on Windows tricks and might use undocumented features, which is only logical since most people (including me) have no idea how they manage to do all that. BTW - I believe Classic Shell is more advanced than StartIsBack++, and might not be affected by WindowBlinds. And which are the resources that WindowBlinds uses so heavily ?

Comment: I'm still interested in knowing which are the resources that WindowBlinds uses so heavily.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that your question was really a question and was addressed to me (my english is not good), how you expect I can know which filesystem resources are managed by WindowsBlinds?,I didn't developed it, but I can englobe it as: "graphic (GDI) resources" consumption

Comment: its a "huge" app fulll of features,the UI is a little bit slow (too much resources to draw on the UI = non-responsiveness = excesive heap consumption), it is an app that is running in background for the lifetime of the user session...

Comment: it changes the common theming environment with a custom theming mechanism with their rules (whichever rules they could be, faster or slower, producing more or less consumption) with a lot of visual effects, things that implies much consumption (in comparisson with "X" if you want to see it in that manner) and probablly a lot of continuous calls to "Y" undocumented functions (addressing what you said) to handle everything right at the unmanaged side of coding level, and it also registers some dlls that are loaded in each session and seems in continuous usage...

Comment: For all those reasons (and for a profilling test I did) I said Windowsblinds consumes much I/O device operations, and RAM consumption, of course, I can't take this application as a solution for a single problem with "window borders", since using Windowsblinds will cause me other kind of "problems" if we understand this in a performance point of view, I don't want to keep this program running on background and doing the things that it does, just because I don't need this app, but is a professional app that can help other people to personalize their desktops, of course, that is good!.

Comment: I was thinking of taking my own advice and buying WindowBlinds. I understand that you feel that this software is too invasive and hooks too much into Windows. My worry is really if it affects the running or the performance of Windows itself - did this happen to you?

Comment: well, not in a excesive meaning, I can't say: "woah! this program makes my O.S. really slower", not at that point, just it adds a consumption factor that if you have more programs running in background then maybe in that case you could start noticing signs of bad performance... I'm no one to say whether you have to buy the program or not, if you like like it, then try it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I will try to see what WindowBlinds does. But as far as I know, Windows development is now chaotic, in the sense that more and more is done in software, rather than via registry parameters. This is the case for border-width, where the old registry settings no longer work in Windows 10 although they worked fine just until 8.1. To circumvent Windows software, WindowBlinds has now no choice but to hook into Windows. But I will check that out.

Comment: I have tried WindowBlinds and decided not to buy. It is a theme editor, and some of the settings do not work in Windows 10, presumably those that are now hard-wired by Microsoft. Although it does solve your problem. My opinion is that creating a theme is the only way now to modify borders, and that some useful options that were available before are no longer available in Windows 10, There is nothing that we can do about it except go back to a previous version of Windows (I don't recommend this).

Comment: I also agree that the installation of WindowBlinds is huge, but it contains lots of theme elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Divvy? They have a windows version and I believe I use it in the same way you use Sizer. I just tested to see if I get a gap between windows using Divvy by putting a bright blue mspaint behind two chrome windows sized using Divvy and I couldn't see through the windows to the background.

I know it's a paid product and not necessarily the fix you're looking for but seems to be able to do what you want Sizer to do. Perhaps it internally corrects for the transparency you're mentioning in Win 10.

[Divvy Link (Windows)](http://mizage.com/windivvy/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this application has much more problems than **Sizer**. The main problem is that It doesn't support custom positions and sizes, in other words is not customizable, you need to put a window on predefined and very little rectangles, the second problem is that don't works as **Sizer**, you need to open the program and select one of the very little rectangles every time, and last problem is it doesn't take into account the taskbar space, when you try to put a window in a corner using **Divvy**, the window will end-up covered by the Windows taskbar, at least on **Windows 10**

Answer (score 1):

Copy - paste from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/dukizv/how_to_increase_border_thickness/) because links die...

> On the default theme, you can change the border padding, although the change will be invisible (you'll still be able to resize the window with the now-thicker border though). To do so, you just need to open the Registry Editor, and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics From here, just edit the value called PaddedBorderWidth. The formula is -15*border width, so if you wanted a 4px thick border, you can set -60. Just sign out and back in or restart and you'll be able to utilise the changes.

> Alternatively, you can enable the Aero Lite theme, which is very similar to the Windows 8 theme. It already has the thicker borders by default but they can be customised the same way as above, however you'll actually see the changes. To enable the theme, navigate to C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero\ and run aerolite.msstyles (aero.msstyles is the default theme if you want to switch back).

> f this is too much effort, you can use [WinAero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/), which has a GUI to alter all these settings and loads more stuff, and reset buttons in case you break something. However, as a general warning, there are some bugs with altering window border thickness and scaling, so I'd only recommend attempting this if you have your scaling set to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I've been so frustrated by this so many times!

Sometimes this has worked:

> Settings > Themes > Colors
>
> Show accent color on the following surfaces
>
> [x] Title bars and window borders

But today on a new virtual PC it didn't work.  But this did work:

> This PC > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Performance > Settings ...
>
> [x] Show shadows under windows

What those 2 things do is a little different, but the result of each is that I can tell where the borders of any window are.