# On Windows 11, is there a way to make the window borders visible aside from the high contrast Accessibility options?

Tags: windows-11, accessibility, border, contrast, appearance

In a sea of dark/night themed windows, I find it very difficult to find where one window ends and the other begins as the borders are nearly invisible on my large 4K monitors.

In Registry Editor I have already navigated to

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

and set both "BorderWidth" and "PaddedBorderWidth" to -2730.

Surprisingly, this gives me a very large title bar, which is indeed helpful.
However, the actual borders which I hoped to modify remain as obscenely thin as heroin-addicted anorexic supermodels from the 1980s.

How can I fatten them up?

Note: Through further experimentation I've discovered I am getting nice fat borders, but the problem is really that this border is INVISIBLE!
And this is a bug which has existed since Windows 10!

See also: [Is it possible to turn visible the invisible window's borders of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1098708/is-it-possible-to-turn-visible-the-invisible-windows-borders-of-windows-10)

Comment: Try a larger scale (Settings, Display).  Otherwise  I do not think you can do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @John,  I just want to change the borders.  I want everything else exactly as it is.

Comment: Indeed, this is my question too. In Windows 10 I used the Aero Lite theme to get my beloved plump borders, but it can't seem to get Win11's borders to eat more calories.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can not change the windows border width in Windows 11 (I have tested on version 22h2. Maybe Microsoft fixes this on a later version).

---

I have [read it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trying-to-increase-border-width-and-regedit-not/5505a5f0-a4d0-40a9-9834-0c86f13bf3b1?page=1) and [read it again](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-windows-border-missing/) but did not believe it. I have tried by changing the classic registry entries `PaddedBorderWidth` & `BorderWidth` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` and then logging off or restarting. No difference. I have tried running Winaero Tweaker and tweaking (after enabling Aero Light Theme as instructed). No difference

Comment: "...(not until version 22h2 at least)." Are you hinting that it might get changed in the future? Thanks for reporting that Winaero Tweaker doesn't help - it was suggested to me on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/window-borders/e039f5dd-a84f-411b-a94a-02c24566fdfa but I never got around to trying it after all the other suggestions that didn't work.

Comment: No unfortunately it's not a hint @OsakaWebbie

Comment: Not sure why you thought 22H2 might change anything. I'm on 22H2 now and it still isn't possible.